# pgfgantt high temporal resolution

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to create a GANTT chart that covers 3 years and (this is the issue) where I can create work packages in daily resolution. Currently, I'm at this point:

```
\documentclass[%
       a4paper,%
       oneside,
       10pt,
       ]{article}

    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{xcolor,color,colortbl}

    % Tikz packages
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    % GANTT plots
    \usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \ganttset{group/.append style={blue},
    milestone/.append style={red},
    progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red},
    bar/.append style={fill=white!40!black!20,draw=blue}}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    \subsection{GANTT chart}
    \label{cha:manage_planning_barchart}
    % -------------------------------------------------
     \begin{figure}[!htb]
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform        shape}]
     \begin{ganttchart}[
            vgrid,
            hgrid,
            bar label anchor/.append style={align=left},
            bar/.style={fill=blue,draw=blue},
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=blue!40!black!20},
            bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black},
            group label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=25em},
            y unit chart=0.65cm,
            %x unit=0.5cm,
            milestone label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=10em},
            Mile1/.style={milestone/.append style={fill=red}},
            time slot format=isodate,
            today=\the\year-\the\month-\the\day,
            today offset = 0.5,
            today label=Today,
            today label node/.append style={anchor=north west},
            today label font=\itshape\color{red},
            today rule/.style={draw=red, thick, dashed}
          ]{2019-02-1}{2019-10-31}
      \gantttitle{My long project}{33}\\
      \gantttitle{2019}{11}
      \gantttitle{2020}{12}
      \gantttitle{2021}{10}\\
      \gantttitlelist{2,...,12}{1}
      \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}
      \gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \ganttnewline
      \ganttmilestone{START!}{2019-02-18} \ganttnewline
      \ganttgroup{First group}                         {2019-2-18}{2019-4-31} \ganttnewline
      \ganttbar[progress=10]{First task in first group}{2019-2-18}{2019-3-31} \ganttnewline
      \ganttbar[progress=0]{Second task in first group}{2019-3-31}{2019-4-31}

      \end{ganttchart}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{GANTT-Chart}
     \label{fig:GANTT}
     \end{figure}
     \end{landscape}
     \end{document}
```

This gives:
[image: GANTT over multiple years]

Can anyone explain to me (1) why it cuts off at the very right and (2) how I get daily resolution over the 3 years?

Thanks much!!